# Date Regular Expression Validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, date

I have a regular expression validator on a text box to validate that the text entered is a valid date.

See reg ex below:

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$"
```

Now I want to allow the following in the textbox: mm/dd/yyyy
How can I update my regex so that if mm/dd/yyyy is entered it does not throw a validation error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really want to catch a valid date you should ensure that month is not greater than 12 and day is not greater than 31 or your day is not zero ...

Comment: I totally agree. I'm currently doing this validation server side :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9m]{1,2}/[0-9d]{1,2}/[0-9y]{4}$"
```

Basically allows 0-9 or m in the first field, 0-9 or d in the second, 0-9 or y in the third (in regular expression `[]` brackets contain a list of possible options, `-` denote ranges of values when placed within brackets).

Answer (score 0):

This is a more accurate way to restrict the Date to a more meaningful format

```
^[1-12]{1,2}/[1-31]{1,2}/[2000-2050,1900-1999]{4}$
```

This is still not perfect as this will allow - for instance - a date 02/31/2013. 
Just realized this is quiet buggy.